# How to fix Feature not enabled problems

Tags: api, mapbox, directions

I currently have an issue that whenever I connect my MapBox map to the Directions API, an error is returned which says '{"message":"Feature not enabled"}'.
I have looked around and have not found anywhere where I can enable this feature, and would like to know if there is a way that you can do it.
Thanks in Advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/directions/

First line:

> This API is a preview and may be changed or removed at any time. Contact us to get testing access to this API.